# Is $f(x) = (ax+1)^b$ a power law?

Tags: functions

Pardon my ignorance, but is it appropriate to call the following function a "[power law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law)"?

$f(x) = (ax+1)^b, x \ge 0$

(Update) It is given that $b \le 0$.

Comment: Law? What is the "law" about this function?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law

Comment: No, because the it is not [scale invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law#Scale_invariance) (because $ax + 1$ isn't [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial)).

Comment: According to that page, you have created a "power law" relating $ax+1$ and $f(x)$, but this is different from a "power law" relating $x$ and $f(x)$ as mentioned by !A.P.

Comment: Power law sounds like something from physics. I don't think I've heard it in a mathematical context before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = (ax+1)^b, x \ge 0$

Test scale invariance:
$$f(cx)=(acx+1)^b=c^b\left(ax+\frac{1}{c}\right)^b\neq d(ax+1)^b=d f(x)$$

Comment: Which is unfortunate.. The problem is that my function has to satisfy $f(0)=1$, otherwise it will not make sense. Would it still be OK to informally talk about "power law" sort of relationship, or would that be a complete no-no?

Answer (score 0):

No, this type of function may be a *polynomial*, but it doesn't describe any "property"( or law/theorem) for that matter.

Comment: But if $b$ is not an integer it's not even a polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Law is something which implies a statement which is always true (or is true given some conditions hold true). In a way you may consider theorem, statement, lemma all synonyms of law. Here there's no law. It would be a law, if it was saying `f(x) = some other function` or `f(x) is some special type of function (say continuous)`. So at least I don't see a law here ( as there's no statement made about the given function f(x) ).

Comment: By "power law" I mean this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law
That's not really a law as in physics, just a fancy name.